# OBIEE Charts do not show because of adobe flash player

Tags: oracle, obiee

OBIEE uses flash player to render charts. After discontinuing support of adobe flash player, obiee charts do not display. Is there any way to render obiee charts without adobe flash player.

Answer (score 1):

OBIEE doesn't use flash anymore since many years because it's dead technology. You didn't upgrade and now get penalized. Any version that still uses flash is out of date and unsupported.